# Invalid plugin specification moor_ffi Cannot find the `flutter.plugin.platforms` key in the `pubspec.yaml`

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I upgraded flutter to the latest version and now everytime I try build I get this error.

> Invalid plugin specification moor_ffi.
> Cannot find the `flutter.plugin.platforms` key in the `pubspec.yaml` file. An instruction to format the `pubspec.yaml`
> can be found here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#plugin-platforms

I'm not quite sure how to go about fixing this since there isn't much online about this error and I only started using flutter in the past couple of days.

Here is my `pubspec.yaml` file

```html
name: pattle
description: An easy to use Matrix app.

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  matrix_sdk: ^0.33.0+1

  async: ^2.3.0

  bloc: ^3.0.0
  flutter_bloc: ^3.2.0
  provider: ^4.0.1
  equatable: ^1.0.1

  intl: ^0.17.0

  cached_network_image: ^2.2.0+1
  flutter_cache_manager: ^1.1.3

  path_provider: ^1.6.5
  path: ^1.6.4

  sentry: ^3.0.1

  device_info: ^0.4.1+1
  package_info: ^0.4.0+5

  # TODO: Use official package when PR is merged
  flutter_html:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/pattle-org/flutter_html.git
      ref: 71406a09f9e591f9d35635e6a086007ccc678ae3

  flutter_dotenv: ^2.0.1
  transparent_image: ^1.0.0
  photo_view: ^0.4.2
  url_launcher: ^5.1.0
  image_picker: ^0.6.1+3
  image: ^2.1.4
  mime: ^0.9.6+3
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+4
  mdi: ^2.0.0
  shimmer: ^1.1.0
  flutter_svg: ^0.17.3+1
  animations: ^1.0.0+5
  characters: ^1.1.0
  vibration: ^1.2.4
  video_player: '>=0.10.11+1 <2.0.0'

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
  firebase_messaging: ^6.0.13

  flutter_local_notifications: ^0.8.4

dependency_overrides:
  moor_ffi: 0.5.0
  intl: 0.17.0-nullsafety.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.2+1

  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  effective_dart: ^1.2.1

  intl_translation: ^0.17.9

flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path_android: "assets/logo/launcher.png"
  image_path_ios: "assets/logo/launcher_full.png"
  adaptive_icon_background: "#aa4139"
  adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/logo/launcher_foreground.png"

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
  - .env
  - assets/logo/logo.svg

  fonts:
    - family: CreteRound
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/crete_round_regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/crete_round_italic.ttf
          style: italic
```

Any ideas what is causing this?

This may be the answer
https://github.com/simolus3/moor/issues/727#issuecomment-662935493

But I'm not sure what this person means by

> add a dependency on the new sqlite3_flutter_libs package

> drop the moor_ffi dependency and replace imports with the new package:moor/ffi.dart library

Since I'm very new to flutter

Answer (score -1):

```
flutter clean; pubdev get
```

worked for me